# Using an indexed list as a value in data dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm new to Python and trying to build a data dictionary from a csv. I don't have a lot of flexibility to change the csv. I'm not sure if it would be easier (or even possible) to use a list as a value in a data dictionary, and then access a specific value in that list with some kind of index, or if I should import the data to have an additional key with only a float as the value.

Here's a sample of the structure in a csv:

```
Tester = [[1, 1, 3, 1, 10, 5, 10],
          [1, 2, 3, 7, 5, 3, 8  ],
          [1, 4, 5, 9, 7, 2, 8  ],
          [2, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0  ],
          [2, 3, 5, 6, 4, 3, 2  ],
          [2, 5, 6, 7, 10, 4, 4 ],]
```

I'm not sure how to produce this dictionary, with four keys:

```
(1, 1, 3, 1) = 1
(1, 1, 3, 2) = 10
(1, 1, 3, 3) = 5
(1, 1, 3, 4) = 10
(1, 2, 3, 1) = 7
(1, 2, 3, 2) = 5
(1, 2, 3, 3) = 3
(1, 2, 3, 4) = 8
(1, 4, 5, 1) = 9
(1, 4, 5, 2) = 7 
...
```

Currently, I'm instead using a list as the value and getting the following output. I could leave the output as is, but then I'm getting a value error. Or, I could try to produce the output above, but I'm not sure how to do that. What this actually represents mathematically is a variable with four subscripts, so I'm not sure what the best practice would be here.

```
# Import libraries
from gurobipy import *
import csv
from math import *
import numpy as np
from random import *
import time

# arc capacity
capacityatest = open('C:/Users/Emma/Documents/2021-2022/Thesis/Data/tester.csv', 'r')
csv_capacityatest = csv.reader(capacityatest)
mydict_capacityatest = {}
for row in csv_capacityatest:
        mydict_capacityatest[(row[0], row[1],row[2])] = list(row[3:7])
print(mydict_capacityatest)

arc, capacityatest = multidict(mydict_capacityatest)

{('1', '1', '3'): ['1', '10', '5', '10'], ('1', '2', '3'): ['7', '5', '3', '8'], ('1', '4', '5'): ['9', '7', '2', '8'], ('1', '7', '10'): ['9', '9', '4', '5'], ('1', '11', '12'): ['3', '4', '4', '7'], ('2', '1', '2'): ['0', '0', '0', '0'], ('2', '3', '5'): ['6', '4', '3', '2'], ('2', '5', '6'): ['7', '10', '4', '4'], ('2', '9', '10'): ['3', '2', '1', '7']}
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-b7e72ced1492> in <module>
     15 print(mydict_capacityatest)
     16 
---> 17 arc, capacityatest = multidict(mydict_capacityatest)

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Comment: If `multidict` is `https://multidict.readthedocs.io/en/stable/multidict.html#multidict`, then why are you expecting the constructor to give two values to unpack? The multidict has many more values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're iterating over each row, also iterate over the elements 3 onwards (`row[3:]`). You can use the `enumerate()` function with a second argument to have the index start at 1. Then, construct your key using the first three elements of your row, and the new "index" of the item. Then, simply assign that value to that key in the dictionary. No need for multidicts.

```
csv_capacityatest = [[1, 1, 3, 1, 10, 5, 10],
          [1, 2, 3, 7, 5, 3, 8  ],
          [1, 4, 5, 9, 7, 2, 8  ],
          [2, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0  ],
          [2, 3, 5, 6, 4, 3, 2  ],
          [2, 5, 6, 7, 10, 4, 4 ],]

mydict_capacityatest = {}

for row in csv_capacityatest:
    key_start = row[0:3]
    for index, item in enumerate(row[3:], 1):
        key = tuple(key_start + [index])
        mydict_capacityatest[key] = item
```

Which gives this dict:

```
{(1, 1, 3, 1): 1,
 (1, 1, 3, 2): 10,
 (1, 1, 3, 3): 5,
 (1, 1, 3, 4): 10,
 (1, 2, 3, 1): 7,
 (1, 2, 3, 2): 5,
 (1, 2, 3, 3): 3,
 (1, 2, 3, 4): 8,
 (1, 4, 5, 1): 9,
 (1, 4, 5, 2): 7,
...
}
```

Comment: I agree with "no need for multidicts". I would have answered with basically the same solution, except that I would have tried to replace the loops with list comprehensions :)

Comment: @orithena I find that comprehensions are hard to _comprehend_ when you're a beginner, especially if you have nested loops.  It's much easier to write it out as a regular loop first, and _then_ convert it to a comprehension if you really want to. Also, slight nit-pick: this would have been a _dict_ comprehension, since we're creating a dictionary

Comment: Thanks you! Super quick follow up question: I assume in the original coding, using arc, capacitya = multidict(mydict_capacitya) renames the key to arc and the value to capacitya? How would i do this without using multidict?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I see what you did there :D (You're right, though in case of python, I would try to teach comprehensions very early.)

Comment: @EmmaKuttler I just realized that you use the [multidict function of gurobi](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.5/refman/py_multidict.html) ... no, multidict() returns a tuple of `(keys, dict1, dict2, ... dictn)`, and the list of keys is then referenced by `arc` in your code. Also, I don't see what that multidict should accomplish, its documentation is pretty minimal...

Comment: @EmmaKuttler you'd need to iterate over the dictionary to get _each_ key and value pair individually, or get a list of keys and values using `.keys()` and `.values()`